# Bake multiple types of textures into a single texture for easy conversion to different styles

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

I need to take the three textures I have (roughness map, normal map, and diffuse) and bake the information loaded onto each of these into a single diffuse texture.

To further illustrate what I mean, here's a picture:

[image]

I need to convert this semi-realistic model into one ready for NPR-style shading. But you can see that when I switch the viewer to the diffuse texture it loses some detail, such as the checkerboard pattern on the back and the colour switch on the lapels. (caused by the roughness and normal maps).

[image]

Is there a way I can convert all of this information into a single diffuse texture? I really thought this was possible within Blender. Another idea I have is to just put the roughness/normals onto the diffuse texture as a multiply layer in Photoshop, but I'm not sure if it would look as good or retain the details as well.

Thank you.